# Parse multiple objects with GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

At the the moment i can correctly parse a JSON like this:

```
"assignments:[{"
    + "'id': '111',"
    + "'erporder_erpid' : '132',"
    + "'dtStart' : '10:00 12-12-12',"
+ "}]";
```

with GSON. But I don't know the appropriate way to parse multiple objects like:

```
"assignments:[{"
    + "'id': '111',"
    + "'erporder_erpid' : '132',"
    + "'dtStart' : '10:00 12-12-12',"
+ "},"
+ "{"
    + "'id': '111',"
    + "'erporder_erpid' : '132',"
    + "'dtStart' : '10:00 12-12-12',"
+ "}]"
```

I have a correctly set up Javabean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
"assignments:[{"
        + "'id': '111',"
        + "'erporder_erpid' : '132',"
        + "'dtStart' : '10:00 12-12-12',"
    + "},"
    + "{"
        + "'id': '111',"
        + "'erporder_erpid' : '132',"
        + "'dtStart' : '10:00 12-12-12',"
    + "}]"
}
```

Objectclass.java

```
public class takeData {
public List<assignmentsData> assignments;


    public List<assignmentsData> getAssignments() {
        return assignments;
    }

    public void setAssignments(List<assignmentsData> assignments) {
        this.assignments = assignments;
    }
}
```

assignmentsData.java

```
public class assignmentsData {
    public String id="";
    public String erporder_erpid="";
    public String dtStart="";


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getErporder_erpid() {
        return erporder_erpid;
    }

    public void setErporder_erpid(String erporder_erpid) {
        this.erporder_erpid = erporder_erpid;
    }

    public String getDtStart() {
        return dtStart;
    }

    public void setDtStart(String dtStart) {
        this.dtStart = dtStart;
    }
}
```

parsingClass.java

```
Gson mGson= new Gson();
Objectclass mObjectclass=gson.fromJson(jsonString, Objectclass.class);
```

Access :*mObjectclass.getAssignments.get(0).getId();*

Comment: Thanks your answer! However it absolutely refuses to do getAssignments from the object class. getAssignments cannot be resolved, weird since it's definitely declared in Objectclass.

Comment: clean the project and make sure everything declared in Public

Comment: also append "{" "}" extra braces in your json string

Comment: getAssignments is still borked, accessed it with mObjectclass.assignments 'cause you made that public, and it works :)

Comment: so are you able to parse now?

Answer (score 3):

You can use below method :

```
JSONArray outerArr = new JSONArray("assignments"); 
for(int ictr=0;ictr<outerArr.length;ictr++)
{
        JSONObject obj =outerArr.getJSONObject(ictr);
        String id=obj.getString("id");
        String erporder_erpid=obj.getString("erporder_erpid");
        String dtStart=obj.getString("dtStart");
}
```

Hope this may help to you.

Comment: @MaikelS why not to use and inbuilt functionality rather using external Library to parse JSON.

Comment: I would like to use GSON, it's much simpler. In reality i don't have three strings, but hundreds. I used this example to simplify my question. And be honest: you can't beat this:


            Assignment data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Assignment.class);